# JPA 2.2: Using find method to retrieve data from mysqlDB

Tags: java, mysql, openjpa

I´m using JPA 2.2(Openjpa) running on OpenLiberty and mysqlVer 15.1 Distrib 10.1.21-MariaDB.
I have an object call Account where I use the entityManager.find to retrieve a given record.
The record is indeed retrieved but only this column "status" returns null. 
But when I do the manual select against the DB,the value is there.

My Entity class
Account

```
package br.com.rsm.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OrderBy;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

//@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_account")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="Account.findByEmail", query="SELECT a FROM Account a where a.email = :email"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Account.findByCpf", query="SELECT a FROM Account a where a.cpf = :cpf"),
    @NamedQuery(name="Account.findByUserId", query="SELECT a FROM Account a where a.userId = :userId")
})


public class Account implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String userId;
    private String fullname;
    private String email;
    private String birthdate;
    private String cpf;
    private String rg;
    private String address;
    private String addressNumber;
    private String complement;
    private String cep;
    private String state;
    private int city;
    private String phone;
    private String mobile;
    private String carrier;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
    private long leftSide;
    private long rightSide;
    private Timestamp created;
    private String parentId;
    private String parentSide;
    private String networkSide; 
    private Timestamp activated;
    private double points;
    private String nickname;
    private String nis;
    private String whatsapp;
    private long bank;
    private String accountType;
    private String branchNumber;
    private String branchDigit;
    private String accountNumber;
    private String accountDigit;
    private String accountOwner;
    private String cpfAccountOwner;
    private String facebookID;
    private double career;
    private double pb;
    private int certID;
    private String automaticRenovation;
    private String emailPagamento;

    @Transient
    private Account rightSideAccount;

    @Transient
    private Account leftSideAccount;

    @Transient
    private boolean searchableBySignedInUser;

    @Transient
    private long totalCandidatosAgente;

    @Transient
    private long totalAgentes;

    @Transient
    private long totalAgentesBracoEsq;

    @Transient
    private long totalAgentesBracoDir;

    @Transient
    private long totalAnjos;

    @Transient
    private boolean cfaCompleto;

    //@Transient
    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner" )
    List<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<Ticket>();

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("created DESC")
    @JoinColumn(name = "accountId" )    
    private List<Score> scores = new ArrayList<Score>();

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("activated DESC")
    @JoinColumn(name = "idAccount" )    
    private List<ProductAccount> productsAccount = new ArrayList<ProductAccount>(); 

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "origin" )   
    private List<Trade> trades = new ArrayList<Trade>(); 

    /**
     * Construtor
     */
    public Account() {}


    public List<Trade> getTrades() {
        return trades;
    }

    public void setTrades(List<Trade> trades) {
        this.trades = trades;
    }

    public List<ProductAccount> getProductsAccount() {
        return productsAccount;
    }

    public void setProductsAccount(List<ProductAccount> productsAccount) {
        this.productsAccount = productsAccount;
    }



    public List<Score> getScores() {
        return scores;
    }

    public void setScores(List<Score> scores) {
        this.scores = scores;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getBirthdate() {
        return birthdate;
    }

    public void setBirthdate(String birthdate) {
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getRg() {
        return rg;
    }

    public void setRg(String rg) {
        this.rg = rg;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAddressNumber() {
        return addressNumber;
    }

    public void setAddressNumber(String addressNumber) {
        this.addressNumber = addressNumber;
    }

    public String getComplement() {
        return complement;
    }

    public void setComplement(String complement) {
        this.complement = complement;
    }

    public String getCep() {
        return cep;
    }

    public void setCep(String cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public int getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(int city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getCarrier() {
        return carrier;
    }

    public void setCarrier(String carrier) {
        this.carrier = carrier;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public long getLeftSide() {
        return leftSide;
    }

    public void setLeftSide(long leftSide) {
        this.leftSide = leftSide;
    }

    public long getRightSide() {
        return rightSide;
    }

    public void setRightSide(long rightSide) {
        this.rightSide = rightSide;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Timestamp created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public String getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(String parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public String getParentSide() {
        return parentSide;
    }

    public void setParentSide(String parentSide) {
        this.parentSide = parentSide;
    }

    public String getNetworkSide() {
        return networkSide;
    }

    public void setNetworkSide(String networkSide) {
        this.networkSide = networkSide;
    }

    public List<Ticket> getTickets() {
        return tickets;
    }

    public void setTickets(List<Ticket> tickets) {
        this.tickets = tickets;
    }

    public Timestamp getActivated() {
        return activated;
    }

    public void setActivated(Timestamp activated) {
        this.activated = activated;
    }

    public double getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(double points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getShortName() {
        if(fullname==null){
            return "";
        }
        if (nickname == null || nickname.isEmpty() ) {
            nickname = fullname;
        }

        if(nickname != null || !nickname.isEmpty()){
            String[] arrTmp = fullname.replace("\n", " ").split(" ");

            String shortName = "";

            if(arrTmp.length >= 2){
                shortName = arrTmp[0] + " " + arrTmp[1] ;
            }else if(arrTmp.length >= 1){
                shortName = arrTmp[0];
            }

            //Passo o limitador de tamanho para ambas situações.
            if(shortName!=null){
                if(shortName.length() > 20){
                    shortName = fullname.substring(0, 19) + "...";
                }
            }
            return shortName;

        }
        return "";
    }

    public String getNickname() {

        return nickname;
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    public String getNis() {
        return nis;
    }

    public void setNis(String nis) {
        this.nis = nis;
    }

    public String getWhatsapp() {
        return whatsapp;
    }

    public void setWhatsapp(String whatsapp) {
        this.whatsapp = whatsapp;
    }

    public long getBank() {
        return bank;
    }

    public void setBank(long bank) {
        this.bank = bank;
    }

    public String getAccountType() {
        return accountType;
    }

    public void setAccountType(String accountType) {
        this.accountType = accountType;
    }

    public String getBranchNumber() {
        return branchNumber;
    }

    public void setBranchNumber(String branchNumber) {
        this.branchNumber = branchNumber;
    }

    public String getBranchDigit() {
        return branchDigit;
    }

    public void setBranchDigit(String branchDigit) {
        this.branchDigit = branchDigit;
    }

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public String getAccountDigit() {
        return accountDigit;
    }

    public void setAccountDigit(String accountDigit) {
        this.accountDigit = accountDigit;
    }

    public String getAccountOwner() {
        return accountOwner;
    }

    public void setAccountOwner(String accountOwner) {
        this.accountOwner = accountOwner;
    }

    public String getCpfAccountOwner() {
        return cpfAccountOwner;
    }

    public void setCpfAccountOwner(String cpfAccountOwner) {
        this.cpfAccountOwner = cpfAccountOwner;
    }

    public String getFacebookID() {
        return facebookID;
    }

    public void setFacebookID(String facebookID) {
        this.facebookID = facebookID;
    }

    public double getCareer() {
        return career;
    }

    public void setCareer(double career) {
        this.career = career;
    }

    public double getPb() {
        return pb;
    }

    public void setPb(double pb) {
        this.pb = pb;
    }

    public int getCertID() {
        return certID;
    }

    public void setCertID(int certID) {
        this.certID = certID;
    }

    public String getAutomaticRenovation() {
        return automaticRenovation;
    }

    public void setAutomaticRenovation(String automaticRenovation) {
        this.automaticRenovation = automaticRenovation;
    }

    public String getEmailPagamento() {
        return emailPagamento;
    }

    public void setEmailPagamento(String emailPagamento) {
        this.emailPagamento = emailPagamento;
    }


    public Account getRightSideAccount() {
        return rightSideAccount;
    }

    public void setRightSideAccount(Account rightSideAccount) {
        this.rightSideAccount = rightSideAccount;
    }

    public Account getLeftSideAccount() {
        return leftSideAccount;
    }

    public void setLeftSideAccount(Account leftSideAccount) {
        this.leftSideAccount = leftSideAccount;
    }

    public boolean isSearchableBySignedInUser() {
        return searchableBySignedInUser;
    }

    public void setSearchableBySignedInUser(boolean searchableBySignedInUser) {
        this.searchableBySignedInUser = searchableBySignedInUser;
    }

    public long getTotalCandidatosAgente() {
        return totalCandidatosAgente;
    }

    public void setTotalCandidatosAgente(long totalCandidatosAgente) {
        this.totalCandidatosAgente = totalCandidatosAgente;
    }

    public long getTotalAgentes() {
        return totalAgentes;
    }

    public void setTotalAgentes(long totalAgentes) {
        this.totalAgentes = totalAgentes;
    }

    public long getTotalAgentesBracoEsq() {
        return totalAgentesBracoEsq;
    }

    public void setTotalAgentesBracoEsq(long totalAgentesBracoEsq) {
        this.totalAgentesBracoEsq = totalAgentesBracoEsq;
    }

    public long getTotalAgentesBracoDir() {
        return totalAgentesBracoDir;
    }

    public void setTotalAgentesBracoDir(long totalAgentesBracoDir) {
        this.totalAgentesBracoDir = totalAgentesBracoDir;
    }

    public long getTotalAnjos() {
        return totalAnjos;
    }

    public void setTotalAnjos(long totalAnjos) {
        this.totalAnjos = totalAnjos;
    }

    public boolean isCfaCompleto() {
        return cfaCompleto;
    }

    public void setCfaCompleto(boolean cfaCompleto) {
        this.cfaCompleto = cfaCompleto;
    }

    /**
     * Adiciona uma nova classe Score
     * @param score Score
     */
    public void addScore(Score score) {
        getScores().add(score);
    }

    public void addProductAccount(ProductAccount productAccount) {
        getProductsAccount().add(productAccount);
    }

    public void addTrade(Trade trade) {
        getTrades().add(trade);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account [id=" + id + ", userId=" + userId + ", fullname=" + fullname + ", email=" + email
                + ", birthdate=" + birthdate + ", cpf=" + cpf + ", rg=" + rg + ", address=" + address
                + ", addressNumber=" + addressNumber + ", complement=" + complement + ", cep=" + cep + ", state="
                + state + ", city=" + city + ", phone=" + phone + ", mobile=" + mobile + ", carrier=" + carrier
                + ", status=" + status + ", leftSide=" + leftSide + ", rightSide=" + rightSide + ", created=" + created
                + ", parentId=" + parentId + ", parentSide=" + parentSide + ", networkSide=" + networkSide
                + ", activated=" + activated + ", points=" + points + ", nickname=" + nickname + ", nis=" + nis
                + ", whatsapp=" + whatsapp + ", bank=" + bank + ", accountType=" + accountType + ", branchNumber="
                + branchNumber + ", branchDigit=" + branchDigit + ", accountNumber=" + accountNumber + ", accountDigit="
                + accountDigit + ", accountOwner=" + accountOwner + ", cpfAccountOwner=" + cpfAccountOwner
                + ", facebookID=" + facebookID + ", career=" + career + ", pb=" + pb + ", certID=" + certID
                + ", automaticRenovation=" + automaticRenovation + ", emailPagamento=" + emailPagamento
                + ", rightSideAccount=" + rightSideAccount + ", leftSideAccount=" + leftSideAccount
                + ", searchableBySignedInUser=" + searchableBySignedInUser + ", totalCandidatosAgente="
                + totalCandidatosAgente + ", totalAgentes=" + totalAgentes + ", totalAgentesBracoEsq="
                + totalAgentesBracoEsq + ", totalAgentesBracoDir=" + totalAgentesBracoDir + ", totalAnjos=" + totalAnjos
                + ", cfaCompleto=" + cfaCompleto + ", tickets=" + tickets + ", scores=" + scores + ", productsAccount="
                + productsAccount + ", trades=" + trades + "]";
    }
}
```

And this is my select result( snapshot table is to big )

```
[
  id=2111,
  userId=99YWK,
  fullname=PatrickRibeiroBraz,
  email=null,
  birthdate=null,
  cpf=null,
  rg=null,
  address=null,
  addressNumber=null,
  complement=null,
  cep=null,
  state=null,
  city=0,
  phone=null,
  mobile=null,
  carrier=null,
  status=null,
  leftSide=0,
  rightSide=0,
  created=2018-06-1212: 09: 29.0,
  parentId=999I2,
  parentSide=null,
  networkSide=null,
  activated=null,
  points=0.0,
  nickname=null,
  nis=null,
  whatsapp=null,
  bank=0,
  accountType=null,
  branchNumber=null,
  branchDigit=null,
  accountNumber=null,
  accountDigit=null,
  accountOwner=null,
  cpfAccountOwner=null,
  facebookID=null,
  career=0.0,
  pb=0.0,
  certID=0,
  automaticRenovation=null,
  emailPagamento=null,
  rightSideAccount=null,
  leftSideAccount=null,
  searchableBySignedInUser=false,
  totalCandidatosAgente=0,
  totalAgentes=0,
  totalAgentesBracoEsq=0,
  totalAgentesBracoDir=0,
  totalAnjos=0,
  cfaCompleto=false,
  tickets={
    IndirectList: notinstantiated
  },
  scores={
    IndirectList: notinstantiated
  },
  productsAccount={
    IndirectList: notinstantiated
  },
  trades={
    IndirectList: notinstantiated
  }
]
```

> **ID    fullname     status**
>
> 2111   Patrick Ribeiro Braz  C

Has anyone went through this before?

Comment: The fact that you have spaces in the name in output in one example and not in the other makes me think you are using different databases or tables, or search within an uncommitted transaction. If you open a new session to your database and run `select status from tb_account where id = 2111`, what do you see?

Comment: Per, the space between the name was removed when I copied and pasted. The DB has the correct value.
And to be honest, I also thought the issue could be on accessing the wrong DB. But it seems the DB access is okay. I do have 2 DBs one for QA and one for Test and both DBs status is set to C.
I also have reboot my server and the issue still going on.
And replying your question, I got the same result as this one
ID fullname status

2111 Patrick Ribeiro Braz C

Comment: This is my connection set up.
```
<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/rsmdb" transactional="false">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="MySQLLib"/>
    <properties databaseName="rsmdb_test" password="{aes}AL+s2+9VH7BDOKvmvFW8l/TEvWyOWL02+VM27tMf267U" portNumber="3306" serverName="localhost" user="someuser"/>
 </dataSource>
```

Comment: Can you update the question with your code for fetching the account?

Comment: I´m trying to add the code but I dont see the edit button to do so.
I´m using CDI to inject the DAO class on my Resource class. I´m using JAX-RS. 
On this specific method I´using the @transaction annotation
`
@POST
@Path("/angels")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackOn = Exception.class)
@Secured
`

Comment: The code continues bellow.<br/>
`
public Response activateAngel(Sponsor sponsor) {<br/>
  String email = JWTUtils.getToken(httpHeaders); <br/>
  Account angel = accountDAO.get(sponsor.getId()).orElse(null);<br/>
  Account contaUserLogado = getRoot(email);<br/>
 List<Sponsor> angels = null; <br/>
  //This is the point where the status comes out null instead of value C.<br/>
 System.out.println("STATUS: " + angel.getStatus());<br/>
   service.activateAccount(angel, contaUserLogado);<br/>
  angels = service.findAllAngels(email); 
 return Response.status(200).entity(angels).build();
}`

Comment: Now I also need the code for the accountDAO class... :-)

Comment: `
public interface AccountDAO {
   Optional<T> get(long id);
}

public class AccountDAOImpl implements AccountDAO {
@Inject @MySQLDatabase
 private EntityManager em;

@Override
 public Optional<Account> get(long id) {
  Account account = em.find(Account.class, new Long(id));
  Optional<Account> acc = Optional.ofNullable(account);  
  return acc;
 }
}`

Comment: A mystery - everything looks ok to me... Have you tried rebuilding and redeploying to make sure you run the latest version? Enable full logging and make sure the query looks ok. Perhaps try debugging it, following the call into em.find()...

Comment: Yes, I have rebuild, redeploy the entire project. No change at all.
As far as the log, somehow I´m not able to get the log for openjpa. I have set it up, but the log just does not show. Maybe I doing something wrong. I havent spend much time on it, but seems this is the opportunity to do so.
One workaround is to force a second query, but I´m trying to avoid this not so elegant code. I really appreciate your help.